# Book about kids killing vampire living in their hotel?

Tags: story-identification, books

Can someone help identify this young adult book, I remember reading it about 10-12 years ago. Some teenagers go on a school trip to Whitby(?) and are staying in a hotel or something, and one of the rooms is occupied by a strange man. During the course of the book, they all acquire seemingly random items (the most memorable for me is a wooden kite which breaks).

At the end the items all become useful for defeating the strange man who turns out to be a vampire (the kite becomes a cross, maybe one had holy water, possibly garlic?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is "[Room 13](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Room_13)" by Robert Swindells.

These reviews from [mumsnet](http://www.mumsnet.com/Talk/primary/a1055602-What-s-Robert-Swindell-s-Room-13) positively identify the kite-as-cross motif:

> A school (Bottomtop Middle!) takes a trip to Whitby. They stay in the
>   creepy Crow's Nest Hotel. There is no room 13 but at midnight things
>   change. The number 13 appears on the door to the linen cupboard next
>   to room 12, only to disappear in the morning. The main character,
>   Fliss, realises that the hotel is occupied by Dracula and that one of
>   her friends is under his influence. She and her best friend must stop
>   him before he claims another victim...
>
> **Also, various kids are "drawn" to collect random items throughout the
>   story; a torch, a stick of rock, a pebble, a kite with a cross as its
>   backbone. These are then utilised to deal with Dracula at the end.**

Comment: Yes it is. As soon as I saw the question this book came to mind :D

Comment: Perfect, brings back a lot of memories :) Figured it'd be Whitby too.